# Using Spark SQL with Spark Streaming

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming

Trying make sense of SparkSql with respect to Spark Structured Streaming.
Spark Session reads events from a kafka topic, aggregates data to counts grouped by different column names and prints it to the console.

Raw input data structured like this:

```
+--------------+--------------------+----------+----------+-------+-------------------+--------------------+----------+
|.  sourceTypes|                Guid|  platform|datacenter|pagesId|     eventTimestamp|              Id1234|  Id567890|
+--------------+--------------------+----------+----------+-------+-------------------+--------------------+----------+
| Notififcation|....................|   ANDROID|       dev|     aa|2018-09-27 09:41:29|fce81f05-a085-392...|{"id":...|
| Notififcation|....................|   ANDROID|       dev|     ab|2018-09-27 09:41:29|fce81f05-a085-392...|{"id":...|
| Notififcation|....................|     WEBOS|       dev|     aa|2018-09-27 09:42:46|0ee089c1-d5da-3b3...|{"id":...|
| Notififcation|....................|     WEBOS|       dev|     aa|2018-09-27 09:42:48|57c18964-40c9-311...|{"id":...|
| Notififcation|....................|     WEBOS|       dev|     aa|2018-09-27 09:42:48|5ecf1d77-321a-379...|{"id":...|
| Notififcation|....................|     WEBOS|       dev|     aa|2018-09-27 09:42:48|5ecf1d77-321a-379...|{"id":...|
| Notififcation|....................|     WEBOS|       dev|     aa|2018-09-27 09:42:52|d9fc4cfa-0934-3e9...|{"id":...|
+--------------+--------------------+----------+----------+-------+-------------------+--------------------+---------+
```

Counts are required for `sourceTypes`, `platform`, `datacenter` and `pageId`.

Aggregating data with following code:

```
Dataset<Row> query = sourceDataset
        .withWatermark("eventTimestamp", watermarkInterval)
        .select(
            col("eventTimestamp"),
            col("datacenter"),
            col("platform"),
            col("pageId")
        )
        .groupBy(
            window(col("eventTimestamp"), windowInterval),
            col("datacenter"),
            col("platform"),
            col("pageId")
        )
        .agg(
            max(col("eventTimestamp"))
        );
```

Here `watermarkInterval=45seconds`, `windowInterval=15seconds` & `triggerInterval=15seconds`.

Consuming the new aggregated dataset with:

```
aggregatedDataset
        .writeStream()
        .outputMode(OutputMode.Append())
        .format("console")
        .trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime(triggerInterval))
        .start();
```

There are a couple of issues:

1. Output data is not printing the counts for each `groupBy` like platform, pageId etc.
2. How to print the output in json format? I tried using `select(to_json(struct("*")).as("value"))` while outputting data on console but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve your problem using the following code snippet:

```
.outputMode("complete")
```